# Warning: \label in float, but not after \caption

Tags: floats, subfloats

In my document, I usually use two following ways to work with pictures:

```
  \begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pic1.pdf}
    \caption{ description ...}
    \label{enz:fig_usm_1f_RLz}
  \end{figure}
```

and combination with package `Subfigure`:

```
 \begin{figure}[ht!]
   \centering
   \subfigure[my subcaption 1 ]{
     \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{subfig1.pdf}\label{my_subfig1}}
   \subfigure[my subcaption 2 ]{
     \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{subfig2.pdf}\label{my_subfig2}}
   \caption{ bla bla bla bla }
   \label{enz:fig_ZD_NLO}
 \end{figure}
```

I have got many warnings from compilers like this:: **\label in float, but not after \caption ...**

- xelatex.exe> This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
- editor: Eclipse with Texlipse plugin

Comment: The warning comes from the `nag` package but when I put your code above inside a minimal document using `nag` and `subfigure` packages I don't get such warning but "No complaints by nag" instead. So my crystal ball is foggy, can you please enlighten it with a minimal but complete document which shows the behavior described by you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the references for the subcaptions will all be wrong if your caption is below the graphic. Put the label always after or *inside* the caption argument.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
   \centering
   \subfigure[my subcaption 1 \label{my_subfig1}]{%
     \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{subfig1.pdf}}
   \subfigure[my subcaption 2 \label{my_subfig2}]{%
     \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{subfig2.pdf}}
   \caption{ bla bla bla bla }\label{enz:fig_ZD_NLO}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I drew from this example that is given in the documentation package Subfigure on page 3 There is:                            \begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfigure[First]{...}\goodgap
\subfigure[Second Figure]{...}\\subfigure[Third]{\label{3figs-c}...}%
\caption{Three subfigures.}
\label{3figs}
\end{figure}

Comment: the package `subfigure` is really outdated, use `subfig` instead

Comment: All examples in the `subfig` package documentation have their `\label` in the content (and not in the caption), too. (And they work fine.) So I see it as a documented behavior that one can put the `\label` inside the content argument, too, and therefore I see nothing wrong in the code of the questioner.